# Background Image disapear in chrome browser

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-image

I am having a weird problem in chrome web browser, When ever i click on any input field, background images with `background-attachment:fixed` disappear, I have tried some solution provided in other similar questions but not a single solved my problem.

Kindly help me to solve this problem. Thanks

Note: I am using Bootstrap 3 for development.

Comment: Without access to your code, we can't help you any better than a Google search could. I'd suggest that you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that displays your issue.

Comment: I have uploaded it live,
http://www.pixelzeesh.com/21theme/
Background of blog section disappears by clicking any input filed.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having similar issue, I must share that I was able to fix this issue by applying following css on the parent wrapper:

```
position:static
```